# How to add the rowId to this updateRow method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm following along with one of Lynda.com's iOS tutorials which provides sample code.  In the file BWDB.h (Bill Weinman Database), there is an updateRow method declared like this

```
- (void) updateRow:(NSDictionary *) record forRowID: (NSNumber *) rowID;
```

In the file that BWDB.h is imported into, the instructor uses an updateRow method like this

```
  [db updateRow:@{ @"a" : @"cuatro", @"b" : @"cinco", @"c" : @"seis" }
                     :[NSNumber numberWithInt:4]];
        for (row in [db getQuery:@"SELECT * FROM bwtable"]) {
            [self dispRow:row];
        }
```

It's raising an error saying, "No visible @interface for BWDB declares the selector updateRow"

Is this because the method is `updateRow:forRowId:` and he's not using the forRowId part in the file where BWDB.h is imported?

I've copied the whole testDatabase method below where he uses updateRow. Is there a way to add forRowId to it to make it work?

```
-(void) testDatabase {
    NSString *dbtn = @"bwtable";
    NSString *dbfn = @"bwtest.db";
    BWDB *db;

    NSDictionary * row = nil;
    if ((db = [[BWDB alloc] initWithDBFilename:dbfn andTableName: dbtn])) {
        message(@"BWDB version %@", [db getVersion]);
        message(@"SQLite version %@", [db valueFromQuery:@"select sqlite_version()"]);
        message(@"create table ...");
        [db doQuery:@"drop table if exists bwtable"];
        [db doQuery:@"CREATE TABLE bwtable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, a, b, c, stamp TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"];
        message(@"insert row with doQuery ...");
        [db doQuery:@"insert into bwtable (a, b, c) values (?, ?, randomblob(8))", nil, @"2" ];
        message(@"lastInsertId: %@", [db lastInsertId]);

        // NSNumber doubles
        message(@"CRUD insert, rowID: %@", [db insertRow: @{ @"a" : @2.0, @"b" : @3.0, @"c" : @4.0 }]);
        // NSNumber integers
        message(@"CRUD insert, rowID: %@", [db insertRow: @{ @"a" : @3, @"b" : @4, @"c" : @5 }]);
        // Mixed
        message(@"CRUD insert, rowID: %@", [db insertRow: @{ @"a" : @"four", @"b" : @5, @"c" : @6.42 }]);
        message(@"rows with getQuery ...");
        for (row in [db getQuery:@"SELECT * FROM bwtable"]) {
            [self dispRow:row];
        }
        message(@"udpateRow 4 ...");
        [db updateRow:@{ @"a" : @"cuatro", @"b" : @"cinco", @"c" : @"seis" }
                     :[NSNumber numberWithInt:4]];
        for (row in [db getQuery:@"SELECT * FROM bwtable"]) {
            [self dispRow:row];
        }
        message(@"count rows: %@", [db countRows]);
        message(@"deleteRow 3 ...");
        [db deleteRow:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]];
        message(@"count rows: %@", [db countRows]);
        for (row in [db getQuery:@"SELECT * FROM bwtable"]) {
            [self dispRow:row];
        }
        message(@"getRow 4 ...");
        [self dispRow:[db getRow:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4]]];

    } else {
        message(@"db failed to init");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

```
[db updateRow:@{ @"a" : @"cuatro", @"b" : @"cinco", @"c" : @"seis" } forRowID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4]];
```

should do the trick